# Use windows user name and password for web login

Tags: asp.net, siemens, s7-1200

I am new to industrial automation development. I am working on simens. And currently, I want to use windows login user name and password for website login using asp.net. let me know if it is possible or not. If yes then how? I will be very thank full to all who answered.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to use windows login user name and password for website login using asp.net.

Sure. Here's the docs

[ASP.NET Integrated Windows Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/integrated-windows-authentication)

This uses IIS's [Windows Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/authentication/windowsauthentication/) which uses NTLM/Kerberos.